# nodejs async.parallel not working properly

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am unable to get proper output when trying to read data from redis and then send it out to user in json format.

This is my code

```
//API to get slot for a particular date range
app.get('/listcapacity/:ticketid/:fromdate/:todate', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.ticketid;
    var fromdate = req.params.fromdate;
    var todate = req.params.todate;
    var result = {};
    var data_output = [];
    var asyncTasks = [];
    var currentDate = new Date(fromdate);
    var between = [];
    var end = new Date(todate);

    while (currentDate <= end) {
        var tempdate = new Date(currentDate).toISOString();
        var dump = tempdate.toString().split("T");
        between.push(dump[0]);
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    between.forEach(function(entry) {

        asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
            client.exists(id+entry, function (err, reply) {
                if (reply === 1) {
                    console.log("Found");
                    client.get(id+entry, function (err, reply) {
                        var output = JSON.parse(reply);
                        data_output = data_output.concat(output);
                    });
                }
                callback();
            });
        });

    });

    async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(){
        // All tasks are done now
        result['data'] = data_output;
        result['response'] = 1;
        result['message'] = 'vacancies list fetched successfully!';
        res.json(result);
    });

});
```

I am always getting the output `{"data":[],"response":1,"message":"vacancies list fetched successfully!"}` 
Even though I have checked that the keys are there in redis and it is always being Found by the application too.
For some reason the redis part is getting executed after the data has been sent to user. Why is this happening? I know redis works in async hence used the async.parallel function to take care of this but even then I endup with the same issue that  I would have if I wouldnt have used async. What is the reason for this?

Comment: you should call `callback` right after setting `data_output` with the concatenated results. Now it's called before the `client.get` call ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `client.get` is an async operation and you have to callback in there. Also, you need an else statement and you need a callback in there as well:

```
//API to get slot for a particular date range
app.get('/listcapacity/:ticketid/:fromdate/:todate', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.ticketid;
  var fromdate = req.params.fromdate;
  var todate = req.params.todate;
  var result = {};
  var data_output = [];
  var asyncTasks = [];
  var currentDate = new Date(fromdate);
  var between = [];
  var end = new Date(todate);

  while (currentDate <= end) {
    var tempdate = new Date(currentDate).toISOString();
    var dump = tempdate.toString().split("T");
    between.push(dump[0]);
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  }

  between.forEach(function (entry) {

    asyncTasks.push(function (callback) {
      client.exists(id + entry, function (err, reply) {
        if (reply === 1) {
          console.log("Found");
          client.get(id + entry, function (err, reply) {
            var output = JSON.parse(reply);
            data_output = data_output.concat(output);

            return callback();
          });
        } else {
          return callback();
        }
      });
    });

  });

  async.parallel(asyncTasks, function () {
    // All tasks are done now
    result['data'] = data_output;
    result['response'] = 1;
    result['message'] = 'vacancies list fetched successfully!';
    res.json(result);
  });

});
```